# Appium: Find element by partial elementId/UID with XPath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, appium, appium-ios

I am working on a test automation for an iOS app.
I use the Appium-desktop-client (1.15.1) on MacOS (10.15) and find an element on Iphone 11 (13.3) via the Inspector with the following attributes:
[screenshot from the attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVbQm.png)

The **goal** is to do the following in java with appium (6.1.0) and selenium (3.13.0):

Find this element via the `elementId` and get the variable value (in this case 2,6 km).

The **problem** is reaching the element. In the Inspector, the `accessibility-id` and the `name` are always equal to the value, which means that I cannot localize the element with them.
The `elementId` is not fixed, it varies after the 3rd block of numbers (that means I can only use the 45000000-0000-0000.) I can also reproduce this `elementId` from the Inspector using the code from the `"UID"` attribute.

To localize the element I tried the following:

```
appiumDriver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@id,'45000000-0000-0000')]");

appiumDriver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@name,'45000000-0000-0000')]");

appiumDriver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@uid,'45000000-0000-0000')]");

appiumDriver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@elementId,'45000000-0000-0000')]");

appiumDriver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@RuntimeId,'45000000-0000-0000')]");

appiumDriver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@ProcessId,'45000000-0000-0000')]");

appiumDriver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class,'45000000-0000-0000')]");
```

However, with all these attempts to locate the element came an `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`.

My **question** now is, what do I have to write in the `xpath` to find the element via the part of the elementId from the Inspector (or the attribute UID) and then be able to read out the value.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this secure option :

```
//*[local-name(@*)="@elementId"][starts-with(normalize-space(string(@*)),"45000000-0000-0000")]
```

EDIT : contains option doesn't work because the elementId is not the first attribute of the element.

Could you try :

```
//*[@*="45000000"]
```

If this doesn't work let's bruteforce this with :

```
//*[contains(@*[2],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[3],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[4],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[5],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[6],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[7],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[8],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[9],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[10],'45000000')]
//*[contains(@*[11],'45000000')]
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. When I run "//*[contains (@name, '2,6')]" it finds the element (but this is not useful for me). If I add these two values to your code, it won't find the element either. But is it somehow possible to do something like "//*[contains (@*, '45000000-0000-0000')]" to see if the element is accessible at all?

Comment: Yes. But you have to correct your XPath : `//*[contains(@*, '45000000-0000-0000')]`. Shorter form : `//*[contains(@*, '45000000')]`

Comment: It does not find an element, but if i want to validate @* with "//*[contains(@*, '2,6 km')]" (to match with the name or the accessibility-id) it also finds no element. So it seems, this is no valid argument for XPath.